# Do I need an internet connection to play Dragon Age: Origins (PC)

Tags: dragon-age-origins, system-requirements

Do I need an internet connection to play Dragon Age: Origins (PC)?

If I do, how does it work? Do you basically need a connected computer to play the game at all, or do you just need to connect once when you install the game?

Comment: What makes you think you would?

Comment: I would not expect it, but I know some games, like Skyrim, try to connect even though they are single player.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to connect once to EA with your EA/Origin login information to activate your DLC. After that, no internet is needed. This is also required if you have the game on Steam.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if the game tries to "phone home" passively when it is running?

Comment: @TylerDurden Yes, it tries to  upload your characters to your Bioware Profile.